# Form inputs defined inside children components Angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, dynamic

I have huge problem because i want to detect changes in dynamic generated form. When I create form and inside it create component which has input element. NgForm can't detect this input and controls is empty. 
Someone knows any solution to this problem?

@Upadate

There is example code I want to detect changes in every next nested input

`goo.gl/cYX2Q1`

Comment: Many people know solution for your problem but first you need to provide your code

Comment: sorry I added example code which explain my problem

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code but I guess your problem. Dynamically created components breaks data binding, it is the problem. You have to imperatively set your input data.

Check this out.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6223

```
this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(ComponentToLoad, this.elementRef, 'host')
                    .then((component) => {
                        component.instance.inputValue = "whatever";                       
                        component.instance.outputValue.subscribe((value) => {
                            // do smth
                        });
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, but i'm not sure that it's the best way.
On input I set formGroup and add every input by method `registerControl`.

https://plnkr.co/edit/OtCUhxT9B21jNBx2rGZ5